# How to find the PID of an app without ADB?

Tags: termux, diagnostics

[The ADB method](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/108740/168293) is easy enough, but I may not have a computer at hand. Can I retrieve the PID with a Termux package or an app, or any other methods (including those which require root)?

Comment: If root is required, F-Droid https://f-droid.org/ apps are certainly preferred.

Comment: @Firelord: A root method is fine, I forgot to mention this in the question.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio: It seems that you deleted the answer -- do you know what the number string displayed on every app page in Netguard was? As noted by Firelord apps can't retrieve PID in modern Android versions.

Comment: I deleted it after realizing that I misunderstood UID for PID. So, it would have given information that would not have been useful.

Comment: @user598527 that must be UID. Also an app might have multiple PIDs e.g. if it forks native processes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Android 7 or above, you need to have access to ADB (either command-line client, or an app which used adb on localhost) or root access to see the PIDs of other processes.

If you are in Terminal emulator app or in Termux app, and you have root access, do this:

```
su
ps -A -o PID,USER,NAME
```

This would output text segregated in three columns: first column as PID, second column is the user which owns the process, and the third column showing the name of the process.

Example output (posting only a snippet of it here):

```
28574 system       net.oneplus.odm
28622 u11_a149     com.oneplus.gallery
28646 u0_a149      com.oneplus.gallery
28701 u11_a149     com.oneplus.gallery:recyclebin
28727 u11_a149     com.oneplus.gallery:contentdetector
28778 root         [kworker/1:2H]
28789 u0_a329      su
28794 root         sh
28872 u11_system   com.oneplus.opbackup
```

Instead of `ps` command, can also use `pidof` as suggested by Yahya Uddin [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/191416/96277).

**Note:** PID and UID are altogether different things. If you are after UID, see [How can I find app name by UID?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/8452/96277)